# How to use combination of keyboard arrow keys

Tags: c++-cli

I am developing a cad software using GDI+ (c++/Cli and framework 3.5). When user wants to move a line I want to use arrow keys. Presently I am using Number Keys 4,6,8 and 3 for left right, up and down and 7,9, 1 and 3 for diagonal. How to get diagonal using Arrow keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Num Lock on, you could still use the 7, 9, 1, and 3 keys as diagonal arrows.

- The 7 is the home key
- The 9 is the page up key
- The 1 is the end key
- The 3 is the page down key

You would have to intercept those 4 keystrokes, and perform the diagonal move line function.

Comment: Hi Gilbert this is how it is implemented now. The user wants arrow keys also to be used. How to use arrow keys instead of 7 for example?

Comment: You have a choice.  If Num Lock is on, you have to intercept and interpret the arrow key stokes, as well as the home, page up, end amd page down key stokes.  If Num Lock is off, you have to intercept and interpret the number key stokes.

Answer (score 0):

Try handling both keyup and keydown events instead of keypress.  Accumulate the directions on keydown, move on keyup.

Comment: Hi Ben could you please explain your idea of how to use arrow keys this way to represent any diagonal for example equivalent to 7?